# Importing sample project into xamarin studio

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm new to xamarin studio and C#. I'm trying to setup provided sample code "Employee directory" in xamarin studio, but don't know how. Does anyone set it up and successfully got to run it?

Comment: @KirkWoll: well i didn't get any documentation on how to import this project into xamarin studio. so couldn't take even step zero of importing this project into IDE. SO, please provide me pointers to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had trouble opening the solution.  First make sure to update your Xamarin studio to the latest version.  Second, if you don't have all of the Xamarin add-ons installed, the the top level `.sln` file (`EmployeeDirectory.Xamarin.sln`) will not work.  For example, I do not have `Xamarin.Android` installed.

However, you can still open the individual `.csproj` files in each subdirectory (`/EmployeeDirectory/EmployeeDirectory/EmployeeDirectory.csproj`, `/EmployeeDirectory/EmployeeDirectory.iOS/EmployeeDirectory.iOS.csproj`, etc.)  The `.csproj` files compile by themselves and should get you off the ground.

Comment: Thanks a lot for understanding my question correctly. I'm from android background, so it never occurred to me that I can simply click the *.sln files in order to get started. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

Just open the EmployeeDirectory.Xamarin.sln file.